# How can I access the document ID dynamically in order to update an array that is stored to a specific user?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

When I hardcode a doc id it works fine but I need it to match the user that is logged in.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fafyp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yDuY.png)

When I try this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Eac.png)

I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj44P.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.